# WCAG 2.0 and css overflow:scroll property

Tags: css, accessibility

We have a huge amount of text for a terms and condition page and my client want the text to be "in a box with a scroll bar" so it doesn't take the whole page and people can simply click "Yes" at the end without actually reading it.

I'm planning on simply using a div with "overflow:scroll" but is it accessible according to WCAG 2.0? I suspect keyboard accessibility might be our problem here unless there's a way out of it.

Comment: A scrolling div is kind of like an embedded scrollable frame.  What is WCAG's position on embedded frames?

Comment: An iframe and a scrollable div are pretty different things to a screenreader. I don't know of any a11y issues with scrollable elements as described in the OP. [G179 Ensuring there is no loss of content or functionality...](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G179.html) is pretty on topic.

Comment: @steveax the only issue I know of is a keyboard-only user couldn't scroll the `<div>` by default. Add `tabindex="0"` to the `<div>` in question so it can be tabbed to then scrolled via arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

`overflow="scroll"` is far more accessible than `frames` and `iframe`s.  As always, test, test, test, but you're absolutely on the right track.

Comment: accessible iframes: http://webaim.org/techniques/frames/ overflow polyfill http://filamentgroup.com/lab/overthrow/

Answer (score 0):

A div with internal scrollbars is equally annoying to all users, not people with disabilities in particular so strictly speaking, that won't be inaccessible according to WCAG 2.0

It's up to the User Agent (browsers and assistive technologies) to provide a mechanism like a scrollbar also usable by disabled people and [UAAG](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/uaag.php) is the recommendation relative to this topic that vendors like MS, NVDA, Google or Mozilla have to respect.

Of course if a mechanism fails in many UA, even if your content is still accessible according to WCAG 2.0 you'd better find a better solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything that would qualify your statement that something "equally annoying" could be considered a pass.  WCAG aims to provide an objective framework around web usability, a relatively subjective domain.  It must be operable, perceivable, understandable, and robust.  If you kick out any of those legs, the whole table crashes...

Comment: @MCTaylor17 WCAG 2.0 isn't ***necessarily*** about improving usability or quality but accessibility. Yes it will improve both in *most* cases but not necessarily (like fixing code without seeing the big picture). Narrow minded project managers and webdevs exist.